# MimeMessage, Content of email, Charset: utf-8

Tags: utf-8, mime-message

I want to save body of email to file .eml or .docx from MimeMessage. I did it. But my message which I saved to this file has one problem with polish characters. Polish letters are false, like: ą, ć, ł, ż.. etc.

First, I tried save content of mail to object, like it is above code.
And created message object from MimeMessage. I set Header of mimemessage object to UTF-8. And set content to mimemessage. Then I save to file mimemessage.
I tried also decoding like this: MimeUtility.decodeText(), but this method has only string on argument. I have object content, and this object contains all body of mail. Convert to string this object should be wrong, I saw this.

```
Object content = messages[1].getContent(); 
MimeMessage cmm = new MimeMessage(session);
cmm.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
cmm.setContent(content, "UTF-8");
```

This is my results of save mail to file (polish text with some false letters):

> Niniejsza korespondencja nie wiÄ…ĹĽe siÄ™ z udostÄ™pnieniem adresu e-mail uĹĽytkownika jakimkolwiek podmiotom trzecim. List zostaĹ‚ wysĹ‚any za zgodÄ… uĹĽytkownikĂłw OnetPoczty i zgodnie z jej Regulaminem.SzczegĂłĹ‚y dotyczÄ…ce mailingĂłw reklamowych moĹĽna sprawdziÄ‡ w ustawieniach konta. W razie dodatkowych pytaĹ„ prosimy o kontakt

This is what it should look like:

> Niniejsza korespondencja nie wiąże się z udostępnieniem adresu e-mail użytkownika jakimkolwiek podmiotom trzecim. List został‚ wysłany za zgodą użytkowników OnetPoczty i zgodnie z jej Regulaminem.Szczegóły dotyczące mailingów reklamowych można sprawdzić w ustawieniach konta. W razie dodatkowych pytań prosimy o kontakt

Where and what can I set (put) that the text will be have no mistakes ?

To sum up, I have: 
    Object content = messages[1].getContent(); 
and I want to -decode- this "content". How to do this ? I encourage to discusses all you.

Comment: Can you add what you expect the text to look like with no mistakes?

Comment: Niniejsza korespondencja nie wiąże się z udostępnieniem adresu e-mail użytkownika jakimkolwiek podmiotom trzecim. List został‚ wysłany za zgodą użytkowników OnetPoczty i zgodnie z jej Regulaminem.Szczegóły dotyczące mailingów reklamowych można sprawdzić w ustawieniach konta. W razie dodatkowych pytań prosimy o kontakt . This is correct text (this is polish text).

Comment: Can you add your full code in your post (not in the comments), minus sensitive info?

Comment: This code is all what I can show.

Comment: I saw that problem is in here: Object content = messages[1].getContent(); Object content is not have polish characters correcly. All rest is good. Everything is ok. Only this object has not correct encoding. Of course, I tried also encoding this object... but I cannot do this. All methods in java have only encoding string, not object. Maybe you know some method in java about encoding object ? This is it will be good solution.

Comment: So when you save to file, it is not showing the right characters? What encoding does the file have?

Comment: I not set encoding in file. I supposed that file is ok. Probably has standard encoding because I have no set here. But object content has false all text. File I create standard, mime message I set charset utf-8, and this all I save to to .eml. And this has wrong text.

Comment: To sum up, I have -- Object content = messages[1].getContent(); -- and I want to decode this "content". How to do this ? I encourage to discusses all you.

Comment: I have this line code: Charset utf8ch = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); How to change this on my object ? How to does works with "content" object ? Please helps.

Comment: What do you want to decode the content to?

Comment: I decided that only "content" is wrong. I think that inside this object is wrong text, that is why I try to decode "content" object with the text inside.

Comment: I create file: File f = new File("abc.doc"); How to do that file will open with utf-8 ? I try to set utf-8 for addition in this file. Text should be read corectly maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Shoud be:

```
message.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```